# Command String parsing tools for NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, command, sails.js

I am using `SailsJS` for an application.  From front-end i.e. `NodeWebkit`user will be entering a command which will be sent to server via sockets.

This command is parsed in back-end and a specific service/controller is called.

Socket code is as follows :

```
socket.on('command', {'command':'user -a -n abhishek -p 123456'})
```

I am using `JISON` for command-line parsing which gets all options in command with their values.

Are there any command parsers better than JISON which I can use here.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: You can check out https://github.com/tj/commander.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use [minimist](https://github.com/substack/minimist) to parse the command.

```
var cmd = {'command':'user -a -n abhishek -p 123456'}
var argv = require('minimist')(cmd.command.split(' '))
console.dir(argv)
```

will produce:

```
{ _: [ 'user' ], a: true, n: 'abhishek', p: 123456 }
```

then you can:

```
if (argv['a']) ....
```

Comment: @Mirosalv If possible could you help me out with this issue in minimist : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27021844/command-validation-in-minimist